# Linux control packet size for specific IP address

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, tcp, tc

I would like to get Linux tool/script to control packet size of specific IP or MAC. For example if IP reach 10 MB then DROP packages with IP tables. I have idea how to DROP, but I don't have idea how to control packet size for specific multiple IP address

Comment: You want to drop packets once an IP has sent more than 10MB of packets?

Comment: yes, it will helpfull if you have more solution..

Answer (score 1):

You want to read `man iptables-extensions` and `man ipset`. You can use ipsets to track IP addresses (iptables with `--add-set`) along with a counter and a timeout. Then you make an iptables rule with `-m set --match-set` (read the docs) and `--bytes-gt`